# Why wont the code write in the notepad file?

Tags: python, file

This is the start of my password code, but I am stuck with one problem which is when you create a new account but this section doesn't work properly.

```
file=open('account.txt','w')
file.write(yes)
file.close
```

But the code won't write yes in the notepad. This then breaks the code and I have to manually go into the notepad file the re-enter no so I can test it. It will get rid of the no but will not replace it.

```py
opn=False
yes="yes"
file=open('account.txt','r')
account=file.read().lower()
file.close

while opn==False:  #loop to have code run after making an 'account'
     if account =='no':  #if statment for making or signing to account
         nusername=input("Please enter a username or email...")  #enter a username
         file=open('username.txt','w')  #opens the username store file
         file.write(nusername)  #writes the username in the code
         file.close()  #saves and closes the file

         npassword=input("Please enter a password...")  #---||---(same but with password)
         file=open('password.txt', 'w')
         file.write(npassword)
         file.close()

         print(yes)
         file=open('account.txt','w')
         file.write(yes)
         file.close
```

Comment: You need to change the writting mode from `w` to `a`. So, instead of `file=open('username.txt','w')` it should be `file=open('username.txt','a'` and so on!

Comment: Some of your calls to `close` have no parentheses. They should be: `file.close()`.

Comment: Use [context managers](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/context-manager-in-python/) instead for opening files, so you don't forget to close them.

Comment: btw, your `opn` variable is always `False`, so the `while` loop will always loop.

Comment: this is only part of the code the opn does become true later in the code when all the username/passwords and entered

Comment: btw it needs to be w as a is append or add and will just add text where as w is write and will override what's already in the file